# Push one object property with the same object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototypejs

I have to frame object structure like below dynamically.

```
   "1":{
    "A":"one.two.three" 
    },
    "2":{
    "B":"three.four.five" 
    },
    "3":{
    "c":"six.seven.eight"
    }, 
    etc....

    Obj ={
    A: "123",
    B: "345",
    C :"678"
    }
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT SHOULD BE AS BELOW

```
  "Parent" :{
     "one":{
       "two"{
          "three" :"123" (from Obj A)
         }
       }
     "three": {
       "four":{
         "five" :"345" (from Obj B)
         }
      }
     etc...`
`   }
```

so i have tried the below approach. But it does not work.

```
Var temp = {}
temp["one"] ="1";
temp["two"] = temp; (and) temp["one"]
temp["three"] = temp; (and) temp["two"]
```

Comment: Really vague question. You'll need to provide your use case requirements through text rather than through code. I'm not sure anyone will be able to interpret your `(and) temp["one"]` "javascript" logic in to requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t={};
var temp=t;
for(var i=3 ; i>0 ;i--){
   if(i!=1)t[i]={};
   else t[i]=i; 
   t=t[i];
}
JSON.stringify(temp);
```

Output is : "{"3":{"2":{"1":1}}}"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj['temp'] = {};
obj['temp']['tree'] = {};
obj['temp']['tree']['two'] = {};
obj['temp']['tree']['two']['one'] = "1";
```

Comment: I can keep only one temp Object( temp = { })

Comment: Input

1:{
A:"one.two.three" 
},
2:{
B:"three.four.five" 
}
3:{
c:"six.seven.eight"
} etc....


Obj ={
A: "123",
B: "345",
C :"678"
}

Output should be : 

"Parent" :{
"one":{
  "two"{
     "three" :"123" (from Obj A)
    }
  }
 "three": {
   "four":{
     "five" :"345" (from Obj B)
     }
  }
  
}